# how to position an object using variables

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, object, points

I'm trying to create 81 picture boxes and have them automatically positioned a certain distance apart from one another but they don't seem to be placing in any logical order. I have to initialize the X point to -1700 for them to even appear on the screen. The following code gets the first 15 where I want them but then they start stacking on top of one another instead of continuing the pattern. This is the result of about an hour of tinkering but initially the logic looked fine. I even had a message box that would display the current X,Y that was being set and it was correct it just would not place them at those coordinates.

```
int X = -1700;
int Y = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
{
    this.Controls.Add(championThumbNailsArray[i]);
    championThumbNailsArray[i].Height = 80;
    championThumbNailsArray[i].Width = 80;
    championThumbNailsArray[i].Location = new Point(X, Y);
   // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(X) + "," + Convert.ToString(Y));
    championThumbNailsArray[i].ImageLocation = akali.grabPicture();
    //championThumbNailsArray[i].ImageLocation = championsArray[i].grabPicture();
    if (X <= 425)
        X = X + 85;
    else
    {
        X = -1700;
        Y = Y + 85;
    }                           
}
```

Comment: What is the control (this) that they are being added to?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for You to add this controls to FlowLayoutPanel. This control will positions these controls for You

Comment: If you have to initilize x to -1700 just to see them then you have something off. Forms start at 0,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as you are expecting

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
            {
                PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
                p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                p.Height = 80;
                p.Width = 80;
                p.Location = new Point(x, y);

                x += 85;

                if (x > 425)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y += 85;
                }

                this.Controls.Add(p);
            }

        }
```

[image]

But I would go with something like @Ed said, a FlowLayout control

Comment: I got it working with your code but I still had to change the X and Y to initialize at x = -170, y = -255 to get it positioned correctly like in the picture. It is working for now but I will be looking into the flowlayout control thank you

Comment: I'd make the slight change of going with `p.Location = new Point((i % 26) * 85, (i / 26) * 85);` to avoid the messy state of `x` & `y` variables, but otherwise this looks good to me. +1 for `FlowLayout` control as a better alternative too.
`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually placing elements use a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).  Add the controls to the panel and let it do the arrangement for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will be trying this out